# permutation in multi dimensional array

Tags: php

I have an array like

```
$arr = array(
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6,7,8]
);
```

I want print the result as a permutation,

```
1,4
1,5
1,6
1,7
1,8

2,4
2,5
2,6
2,7
2,8

3,4
3,5
3,6
3,7
3,8
```

I tried but more confusing for me.  This is just simple array, here it has only 2 inner arrays, but it may be more.

Comment: please show us your best attempt, so we can help you on your way

Comment: @jibsteroos all my attemps stopped in the middle i cannot construct the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use below to achieve this :

```
list($array1,$array2) = array(
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6,7,8]
        );

     foreach ($array1 as $value1){
         foreach ($array2 as $value2){
             echo $value1.",".$value2."<br>";
         }
            echo "<br>";
     }
```

You will get exactly same result as you want.

Comment: This answer is not sufficient, OP clearly saying: _here it has only 2 inner arrays, but it may be more._ So he needs a (recursive) solution that allows for changing structure.

Comment: So if there are three inner arrays, how will you create permutations between them?